# Mongoose not inserting data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm sending a post request to an API I made. The post request sends some data to be stored in my local database.

```
var Loc = require('../models/locationSchema');
module.exports.locationsCreate = function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.name);
console.log(req.body.address);


Loc.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
}, function(err, data){
    console.log('inside callback!');
    if (err){
        res.send('error');
    } else {
        res.send('success');
    }
});
console.log('reached end of function');
};
```

Here is the schema,

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: String, required: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

Mongoose is connecting properly. And my router is correctly handling the post request.

I'm sending a post request using Postman with the name and address. Nothing happens, and after a few seconds, I get 'Could not get a response'. Nothing gets added to the database.

The console prints the name, address, and then 'reached end of function'. It never shows 'inside callback'

Comment: The code looks good to me, I don't get why the callback is not being called.

Are you sure it's connecting properly to the MongoDB server?

Comment: Can you post more details where the  `locationsCreate()` function being called? Have you called `mongoose.connect('db url')` before the  `locationsCreate()` function execution?

Comment: @AntonioVal Yes, it's connecting

Comment: @Karlen Yep, called the connect function. 
The locationsCreate() function is called when the server gets a post request. Really nothing to show there

Comment: do you have called the module in locationSchema file ?

Comment: Let's try with `new Loc()` then `.save()` of the new doc. See what will be the result inside the callback of `save()`. It might give some hints for solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

i see you have a couple of trailing commas ( commas after the last element in the object ) in your objects, try removing them as this is not allowed in JSON and they will affect the execution of your code ( the function in this case ), 
in the schema : `address: {type: String, required: true}, // remove the comma at the end` 
and in the Loc.create : `address: req.body.address, // remove the comma at the end`

Comment: Whoops. In my original file, I don't have any trailing commas. I posted this in a hurry and edited my code in the browser, so forgot to remove those. The issue still persists though

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect to me except for the fact you have not included mongoose module. Hence you are unable to use `create` method of mongoose.
Include mongoose module like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Thus your code should look like:

```
var Loc = require('../models/locationSchema');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.locationsCreate = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.address);


    Loc.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        address: req.body.address,
    }, function(err, data){
        console.log('inside callback!');
        if (err){
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            res.send('success');
        }
    });
    console.log('reached end of function');
};
```

Hope it helps! Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that I've already called the module. My issue still persists..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object of the model/schema.

```
var LocationSchema = require('../models/locationSchema');

 module.exports.locationsCreate = function(req, res){ 
 console.log(req.body.name); console.log(req.body.address);

 var Loc = new LocationSchema();  

 Loc.create({
     name: req.body.name,
     address: req.body.address, }, function(err, data){
     console.log('inside callback!');
     if (err){
         res.send('error');
     } else {
         res.send('success');
     } }); console.log('reached end of function'); };
```